# Let TeXStudio highlight chords (e.g. \[F#]) in songs package

Tags: texstudio, highlighting, songs

I wrote a chordbook with *songs* package and I would really like that TeXStudio highlights the chords. The syntax is like:

```
Oh fre\[F#]edom
```

In the file in `<user>\AppData\Roaming\texstudio\songs.cwl` I can effectively insert any command I want (`\endsong`, `\beginverse`, etc...), but not **\[...]**.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\[` is a standard command to start a math formular in LaTeX. TXS does not provide support for packages that redefine such commands.

Cwls do only cover textual commands, not `\[`. That said, highlighting is not defined by the cwl files. You may try to fix the highlighting by creating a modified [Language Definition][1], which is probably possible. However, there might still be other unwanted effects in the editor.